# Como criar um método findBy customizado para spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa

Eu consigo usar `findById` no controller mas queria saber como faço para criar um `findByQualquer` para outra propriedade da classe.

segue o codigo:

Model:

```
package com.leonardo.pokedex.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.Objects;

@Document
public class Pokemon{

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String nome;
    private String categoria;
    private String habilidade;
    private Double peso;

    public Pokemon() {
        super();
    }

    public Pokemon(String id, String nome, String categoria, String habilidade, Double peso) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.habilidade = habilidade;
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getHabilidade() {
        return habilidade;
    }

    public void setHabilidade(String habilidade) {
        this.habilidade = habilidade;
    }

    public Double getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(Double peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Pokemon pokemon = (Pokemon) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, pokemon.id) &&
                Objects.equals(nome, pokemon.nome) &&
                Objects.equals(categoria, pokemon.categoria) &&
                Objects.equals(habilidade, pokemon.habilidade) &&
                Objects.equals(peso, pokemon.peso);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, nome, categoria, habilidade, peso);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pokemon{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", nome='" + nome + '\'' +
                ", categoria='" + categoria + '\'' +
                ", habilidade='" + habilidade + '\'' +
                ", peso=" + peso +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.leonardo.pokedex.repository;

import com.leonardo.pokedex.model.Pokemon;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;

public interface PokemonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository <Pokemon, String>{

}
```

Comment: Caro Leonardo recomendo que no futuro simplifique a pergunta para o problema em foco, não é necessário adicionar tudo, o ideal é criar um exemplo minimo funcional ou então explicar exatamente aonde precisa de algo se focar nessa parte, que no seu caso é o Repository que você precisava de um método customizado. Editei a pergunta dessa vez para ver se lhe ajuda a entender como formular perguntas futuras, espero que a resposta lhe ajude, e que a edição da pergunta lhe seja útil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que leia a documentação, existem várias formas de criar/ajustar as queries, veja https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Na sua interface você pode criar um método pra query:

```
public interface PokemonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository <Pokemon, String>{
     List<Pokemon> findByTypeAndRegion(String type, String region);
}
```

Ou então usar o `@Query` para customizar a query conforme achar melhor:

```
public interface PokemonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository <Pokemon, String>{
    @Query("select ... query complexa ORDER by ...")
    List<Pokemon> findByBestIV();
}
```

Ou então se for retornar apenas o melhor de todos:

```
public interface PokemonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository <Pokemon, String>{
    @Query("select ... query complexa ORDER by ...")
    Pokemon findByBestIV();
}
```

Supondo que queira uma busca por tipo de pokémon e região ao qual ele tem origem (ps: eu não entendo de JPA, se algo estiver incorreto pode comentar)

Comment: já tinha lido essa documentacao, mas nao funcionou, 
adicionei o seguinte codigo ao Repository:

List<Pokemon> findByCategoria(String categoria);

e adicionei isso ao Controller:

    @GetMapping("/categoria={categoria}")
    public List<Pokemon> getPokemonByCatergoria(@PathVariable String categoria) {
        return repository.findByCategoria(categoria);
    }

Comment: Caro @LeonardoJuniorCavazzola "não funcionou" é ambiguo. Muitas coisas podem não funcionar por muitos motivos, você tem que informar qual mensagem de erro ocorreu.

Comment: enviei uma resposta, me ajuda ai por favor.

Comment: Não precisava formular uma resposta, o campo de resposta é somente para solução do problema. Ok, tente usar o @Query para customizar como deseja filtrar sua query.

Answer (score -2):

Usando a anotação @Query é possível ajustar as suas buscas via Jpql ou Hql, segue abaixo o exemplo em HQL.

> public interface PokemonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository
> <Pokemon, String>{
>
> ```
> @Query("select p from Pokemon p where p.idadePokemon=:idade ...")
> List<Pokemon> findPokemonsByIdade(Long idade);
> ```
>
> }

Sempre que quiser passar um paramâmetro use o modelo de ":'parametro'" como eu fiz em "idade".